# How to load external javascript.php in codeigniter2.1.3?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter

To start this topic off:

This works : [php and external javascript](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/externalphp.shtml)

This leads me to believe that there is some way to echo javascript in a file named javascript.php within the applications/controllers folder as then to include the js src = base_url().'javascript.php' in a view.

I would like the added security of my codeigniter application in my js. It makes sense to me in cases where I might edit the csrf token output to store in a session var instead of a cookie and pass it to the script.php from a controller initially and then I'd have to use ajax to get new ones ,but, the script could be more secure and I wouldn't need to use cookies. I have not seen anything like it so far in all of my searches , but, that does not always mean that its impossible or impractical.

Comment: I could just use php to check server authenication outside of the applications folder before echoing the script or die() , but , an integrated js framework would be cool enough in codeigniter.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question you are looking to/would like to output js code to a view from a controller? That is no problem - it's done all the time. If you want to output just javascript then set the correct header('Content-Type: application/javascript') - or you may just want to include javascript in an html page, in which case you can pass the code via $data[] to the view and include it on the served page wherever that suits you? `$this->load->view('my_view', $data);`

Comment: Yeah something like that. Thank you SaminOz. I suppose I could include the security tokens in the http request initially as well.

Comment: I think what I'll do is create javascript.php out side of the application and check server vars for authentication then echo the script or die and , as , you stated include the source in $data[] whilst loading a view. I could still use session var to store the csrf token but I'd have to find a secure way to get it in my script with out using cookies.

Comment: So the answer was helpful?

Comment: Yes. Your answer helped me to simplify something I was trying make more complicated. I don't want to put the static js on the pages and I wanted to use a variable that was defined in the application. Since I could do neither, was forced to look into other options where I found a reasonable solution.